# RPi.GPIO - Properly Wiring and Setting Up Pins for Button Inputs

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, breadboard

**Edit:** Breadboard, schematic, and code updated.

I accidentally fried my Pi by shorting it out through the GPIO pins, so I figured it would be a good idea to ask for some help before trying my current breadboard layout with my new Pi.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and have connected it to these 2 breadboards:
[image: Schematic]

This is what the breadboard layout looks like IRL:
[image]

Essentially, I want to have these 6 buttons cause the LEDs to light up and for additional code to run when they're pressed.

Using [this resource](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch07.html), I wrote a script in Python 3 to handle inputs from the pins I wired the switches to:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Buttons 1-6
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Button #1
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Button 6

#LEDs 1-6
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT) #LED #1
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT) #LED #6


while True:
    input_state_1 = GPIO.input(4)
    input_state_2 = GPIO.input(17)
    input_state_3 = GPIO.input(27)
    input_state_4 = GPIO.input(22)
    input_state_5 = GPIO.input(5)
    input_state_6 = GPIO.input(6)

    if input_state_1 == False: #if Button #1 is pressed
        print('Button #1 Pressed')
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH) #turn on LED #1
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW) #turn off LED #1
    if input_state_2 == False:
        print('Button #2 Pressed')
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH) 
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.LOW)
    if input_state_3 == False:
        print('Button #3 Pressed')
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.LOW)
    if input_state_4 == False:
        print('Button #4 Pressed')
        GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)
    if input_state_5 == False:
        print('Button #5 Pressed')
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
    if input_state_6 == False:
        print('Button #6 Pressed')
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH) #turn on LED #6
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW) #turn off LED #6

    time.sleep(0.1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

I guess what I'm wondering currently is: Does the breadboard layout look correct for this application, and does the code look correct? Can multiple LEDs and switches share the same Ground pin? Do I need to set up Ground pins in Python?

Comment: Personally I don’t like this method of combining leds and buttons on inputs, Why not have 6 buttons connected to 6 GPIO inputs and 6 leds connected to 6 GPIO outputs then control with software.

Comment: @CoderMike - I've updated the picture and code based on your suggestion -- I hope I understood what you were saying correctly

Comment: Difficult to tell from the photo - are each led and resistor connected to GND and a GPIO output? Are each button connected to GND and a GPIO input? I tend to add a resistor to the GND used for input - just incase. Add a time.sleep(0.1) to the end of your while true loop (avoids intensive loop).

Comment: I believe yes and yes. I've updated the code as well to add a 0.1s sleep at the end of the loop.

Comment: All seems ok to me

Comment: I've got a question for the OP... actually, just something to consider: If you got an answer that included a picture/photo, and it said, "Use this photo for your wiring diagram.", would you be able to do that? I'll guess the answer is, "No". And this is why we have a ["schematic tool"](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question) in this (Raspberry Pi) forum. No criticism - but maybe something to think about?

Comment: @Seamus - Hm, I followed the link you posted, but there is no Schematic button when editing my post. When I try CTRL+M, it just prompts me to enter code, rather than the CircuitLab tool. -- https://i.imgur.com/9Bl2upA.png

Comment: @Rudy: I don't know what's going on... I clicked the `Edit` button below your question, and I did see the icon for the schematic tool. Why don't you start a new question to see if you can get it there... you won't need to actually submit a question as you can cancel after you check to see if the schematic tool is there.

Comment: @Seamus - It doesn't seem to appear when asking a New question, either. Not sure why

Comment: @Rudy: Hmmm... that's odd. Let me put a question in to Meta & see if I can get an answer there.

Comment: @Rudy: We have [an answer](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/are-there-limits-on-user-access-to-the-schematic-tool) to the "mystery of the missing schematic tool". So let me offer my apologies for chiding you to use something that wasn't available to you, and, speaking for myself and some of the others, our thanks for bringing this shortcoming to the fore. I do believe it will be corrected soon, and the schematic tool will be available to all.

Comment: @Seamus: No problem at all. Glad y'all figured it out